# Delete some useless tags

Tags: support

Moderators, could you please delete the tags [pharase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharase), [opposites](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opposites) and [contradictions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contradictions)? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you meant "phrase"? Or did someone really make that tag?

Comment: @MrHen: I really mean “pharase”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as they aren't attached to any questions, they should automatically disappear within 24 hours. If that *doesn't* happen, please report it as a bug!

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, see:

[Should We Zap The Low-Occurrence Tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags)

> I've implemented a routine that removes tags created more than 6 months ago which have been used only a single time. It will run monthly.